# Why does this regex fail in Matlab (but not Octave or regex101.com)?

Tags: regex, matlab, octave

I have developed a regex (based on [How do I use a Python regex to match the function syntax of MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180784/how-do-i-use-a-python-regex-to-match-the-function-syntax-of-matlab)) to try to capture the input and output arguments and function name from a matlab function declaration, here is the regex:

```
^\s*function\s+(?:(?:\[((?:\s*(?:\w+[\w0-9]*)\s*,?)+)\]|(\w+[\w0-9]*))\s*=)?[\s.]*(\w+[\w0-9]*)\s*(?:\(([^)]*)\))?
```

You can see it in action here: [regex at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/J61O9o/1)

At regex101 it works perfectly, but in In matlab, when I try to use this regex, it doesn't work properly, for example, see the below matlab session:

```
K>> argstr = 'function loss = conductionLo7ss (self, Irms, m, DPF)'

argstr =

    'function loss = conductionLo7ss (self, Irms, m, DPF)'

K>> fcn_decl_regex = '^\s*function\s+(?:(?:\[((?:\s*(?:\w+[\w0-9]*)\s*,?)+)\]|(\w+[\w0-9]*))\s*=)?[\s.]*(\w+[\w0-9]*)\s*(?:\(([^)]*)\))?';
K>> [tokens, match] = regexp (argstr, fcn_decl_regex, 'tokens', 'match')

tokens =

  1×1 cell array

    {1×1 cell}


match =

  1×1 cell array

    {'function loss = conductionLo7ss (self, Irms, m, DPF)'}

K>> tokens{1}

ans =

  1×1 cell array

    {'conductionLo7ss'}
```

However, in Octave, it also works fine:

```
octave:8> argstr = 'function loss = conductionLo7ss (self, Irms, m, DPF)'
argstr = function loss = conductionLo7ss (self, Irms, m, DPF)
octave:9> fcn_decl_regex = '^\s*function\s+(?:(?:\[((?:\s*(?:\w+[\w0-9]*)\s*,?)+)\]|(\w+[\w0-9]*))\s*=)?[\s.]*(\w+[\w0-9]*)\s*(?:\(([^)]*)\))?';
octave:10> [tokens, match] = regexp (argstr, fcn_decl_regex, 'tokens', 'match')
tokens =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] = loss
    [1,2] = conductionLo7ss
    [1,3] = self, Irms, m, DPF
  }

}

match =
{
  [1,1] = function loss = conductionLo7ss (self, Irms, m, DPF)
}
```

In case it is helpful, the documentation for Matlab's regexp function is [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btqcoau-6)

What the regex is actually trying to capture is the function input arguments (if there are any) as one block, the output arguments (if there are any) as one block, and the function name. So for example:

```
`function loss = conductionLo7ss (self, Irms, m, DPF)`
Group 2.    9-13    `loss`
Group 3.    16-31   `conductionLo7ss`
Group 4.    33-51   `self, Irms, m, DPF`
```

or

```
`function [loss, arg2] = conductionLoss (self, Irms, m, DPF)`
Group 1.    63-73   `loss, arg2`
Group 3.    77-91   `conductionLoss`
Group 4.    93-111  `self, Irms, m, DPF`
```

to give two examples

Comment: GNU Octave internally uses PCRE so it is no wonder that it works the same as your regex101 example where you've selected PCRE flavor

Comment: It would help if you actually described what you're expecting the regular expression to identify, rather than just in relation to a specific example...

Comment: Try with [this modification](https://regex101.com/r/pZBfnZ/3). Also, if it does not work, try adding `'emptymatch'` option. Or even with `^\s*function\s+(?:(?:\[([^\]\[]+)]|(\w+))\s*=)?[ .]*(\w+)\s*(?:\(([^)]*)\))?`.

Comment: If that does not work, try defining named capturing groups, `^\s*function\s+(?:(?:\[(?<fname>[^\]\[]+)]|(?<fname>\w+))\s*=)?[ .]*(?<fname2>\w+)\s*(?:\((?<args>[^)]*)\))?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, actually, I originally had named capturing groups, but stripped them for the question to keep things clean.

Comment: @Wolfie, I've added some more detail on exactly what I want to capture, but further detail on the possible structure of matlab function declarations is in the linked question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I tried your modification, but with the same results (anyway, is this just the same as the one from the linked question?). The 'emptymatch' option also doesn't work.

Comment: The first comment pattern is practically the same. I thought shorthands inside character classes could be a problem.

Comment: @Andy, true, for what its worth, it also works with all other flavours available on regex101.com (javascript, python, golang)

Comment: You're really over complicating this by trying to output everything in one regexp call... this is a 5 minute job if you just do 3 separate calls (one for outputs, one for function name, one for inputs).

Comment: @Wolfie, true, I guess I could break it down, I did it this way mostly as I was starting from the regex in the linked question

Comment: @Wolfie, however, I would still like to know why it doesn't work in Matlab, but does work elsewhere so I can avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: @crobar maybe report a bug to Mathworks

Comment: Obligatory quote: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." (~ Jamie Zawinski, Netscape)

Comment: It's expected but undesired behavior. regexp does not support nested tokens, even if they are non-capturing. Only the outermost tokens are captured. See the note in the doc: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#btrvwd4

Comment: @matlabbit, indeed, you are totally correct! Well spotted, this is indeed unfortunate, and the root cause of the issue. If you add as an answer I will accept.

Comment: @carandraug, looks like it is a documented bug!